# I want to install and get to building a personal MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, database

So how do I go from installing MySQL from the Software Center to inputing data into fields and bringing in a comma delimited file?

I've only had brief experience with MSAccess and OOo Base a long time ago, so details are appreciated, I just want to get up and running.

I have Ubuntu 10.10, 64 bit, if that affects much. If you can link me to a howto that does exactly what I'm looking for, that would work.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you should have some level of experience in SQL coding if you want to hand code. This means you first get mysql-server [(click-to-install)](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/mysql-server)

For the most basic sql commands, you would need to install `mysql-client` as well. After that open a terminal and run `mysql -u username -p` for running mysql cli. Take a look at mysql documentation for learning mysql.

According to the open-office wiki, Openoffice Base is also integratable with mysql. Take a look [here](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Connect_MySQL_and_Base) for more instructions. There are other mysql-gui tools available for ubuntu, the [most recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721852/developer-tools-to-directly-access-databases) being Squirrelsql. For the export part to csv, I believe Openoffice should be capable of that (I have no experience of using Base)

In case you would like a web based interface, I would recommend [phpmyadmin](http://phpmyadmin.net) and [sqlbuddy](http://sqlbuddy.com) as two possible options. They can connect to external servers as well. So you can run them on other machines as well

Comment: Took the words right out of my mouth Capt. Nemo. Great suggestions. +1 on learning the CLI.. GUI tools are good for discovering options at the beginning, but there's nothing like learning SQL to get the full power of relational dbs.

Answer (score 1):

(1)  `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` in the terminal.  That should set it up.  It'll give you various prompts for the setup process.

(2) **If you need to be able to access this from a different system (and not from the machine you install it on), do this.**  After the config, go find `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`.  Locate any line saying `skip-networking`.  Modify the line to say `#skip-networking`.  *if you do this step, make sure you do `sudo service mysql restart` in terminal before continuing!*

(3)  You will need experience with SQL code to be able to use the system, but all the information you need can be found on the mysql site: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/

Answer (score 0):

I found installing as a complete package from  http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html#374  save LOTS of headaches.  This will set up apache, mysql, and php.

Comment: I wasn't asking about setting up a LAMP stack, I'm not there yet, and how do I know I can trust the site you linked to? For all I know, it could have a trojan.

Comment: I recommend against using XAMPP on Ubuntu. If you need a LAMP stack, there's a metapackage for that. On the other hand, if you have LAMP you can use phpmyadmin, which greatly simplifies MySQL administration. Also, I can vouch for apachefriends.org. XAMPP is not a trojan, just something you don't need.